# zipfile.extractall always gives exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

Here is my script:

```
import zipfile
zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('crack.zip')
passFile = open('passwords.txt')
for line in passFile.readlines():
    password = line.strip('\n')
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print password
    except Exception, e:
    print e
```

These are the contents of passwords.txt:

```
abcde
fghijk
secret
lmnopq
rstw
uvwxyz
```

The file passwords.txt has 5 strings, out of which only one is the correct password for this zip file(As you would have guessed, secret is the correct password). When I run this script , it always goes to the catch block and prints `('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x7f70836d52a8>)` 5 times. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you successfully unzip the file with the right password, you don't stop the loop. Therefore it continues and tries the other three passwords. There are five incorrect passwords in your file so you get five exceptions. To fix this, add a `break` statement.  I rearranged your code a bit, because generally, only the statement you want to catch exceptions in should be in the `try` block.

```
for line in passFile:
    password = line.strip()
    print password
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    else:
        print "success"
        break
```

Comment: the thing is, it never unzips the file , I checked

Comment: Then why is your question about why your script gets five exceptions, instead of why it doesn't unzip the file? (Hint: if it doesn't give you an error, it has unzipped the file. The question is, where?)

Comment: it goes into exception block , hence it never unzips the file

Comment: But it only gives you five exceptions. There are six passwords in the file. Therefore one of them worked.

Comment: sorry , my bad, the password protected file I created in the linux OS didn't work , but the password protected zip file I made in windows with winrar worked. I don't know why though.